# bluebird vs async.js performance

Tags: performance, asynchronous, bluebird, async.js

I understand that promise libraries provide clarity of code structure.
But are they faster?

I am using async.js 'each' to loop through asynchronous xmlHttpRequests. Will it be faster if I adopt bluebird 'all' instead?

Comment: So, your code is waiting on multiple async responses and somehow you think the processing speed of two different callback systems is going to really be significant?

Comment: I also have functions inside async each loop to parse xml responses. So, you think the two different callback systems will not make any significant performance difference? If so, the only reason to choose bludbird over async.js is the different code abstractions between the two call back systems?

Comment: There are lots of reasons to choose promises over the async library. My favorite reason is much more robust and automatic error propagation, particularly in complicated scenarios where you need bulletproof code.  Bluebird is indeed fast, but performance isn't the main consideration here. I'd suggest you read this article for lots of reasons to choose promises: https://spion.github.io/posts/why-i-am-switching-to-promises.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ES6 you don't need any external libraries anymore. You could just use built-in functionality. And if you trying to return an array of results of all of your requests you could user `Promise.all`, which returns a promise as well.
To read more about it here is [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: But isn't bluebird faster compared to the native promise library?

Comment: Native promises are slower. The answer from bluebird author here gives an excellent explanation why.
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/278778/why-are-native-es6-promises-slower-and-more-memory-intensive-than-bluebird

Comment: And here is a lot of data on what is faster and what is using less memory
https://spion.github.io/posts/why-i-am-switching-to-promises.html
I hope it helps